# EF 4.1 using wrong schema in generated sql

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, ef-database-first

I am new to EF and i can't work out what I am doing wrong.  I have used EF 4.1 "database first" to create a model for an existing database (that i can't change).  All of the tables that i need in the database are in a particular schema which for this question i will call "my_schema".  In the main properties of the edmx designer file i have set Database Schema Name to "my_schema".  When i inspect the raw XML of the edmx file it seems to have the correct schema mappings

e.g.

```
<EntitySet Name="Events" EntityType="MyModel.Store.Events" store:Type="Tables" Schema="my_schema" />
```

However the SQL generated when i access the Events entity set on the DbContext class is still:

```
SELECT ....
FROM dbo.Events
```

I am not sure if it makes any difference but i am using the ADO.net DBContextGenerator to generate my classes.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I can offer specific advice, but have you used Find In Files to search for the string `"dbo"` in your model source code? That might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I am using pocos and convention based mapping so the actual generated c# source code of my entity and context classes does not have any databasey stuff in it.  There are no references to dbo in the xml source of the edmx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i have sussed this now and it boils down to my ignorance of how EF works. I was passing my DbContext an ordinary ADO.net connection string which seems to flip it into code first mode. As such any settings and configuration in my edmx model were ignored and it was looking for attributes on the model classes. As soon as i changed it to use an EF string that includes references to the model metadata files it works. Seems obvious now, no idea how i expected it to magically know about model metadata.

Comment: When we don't understand how something works, it always seems like magic.

Comment: What does an EF Connection String look like and what does an ADO.net Connection String look like?  I've got the same problem but mine has `application name=EntityFramework` and `providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"` in the connection string (which looks very EF to me).